# How to disable the @EnableWebSecurity and @EnableMethodSecurity features of Spring Security through the configuration file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

In some cases, such as troubleshooting, security checks can cause obstacles for us, but I cannot quickly turn them off. I must remove @EnableWebSecurity and @EnableMethodSecurity, recompile the project, and put it on the server before troubleshooting.

After adding @EnableWebSecurity and @EnableMethodSecurity, I customized parameters in the configuration file to disable SpringSecurity. However, SpringSecurity no longer validates my token, but @PreAuthorize is still working. Here is the code.

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, JwtAuthenticationConverter converter) throws Exception {
        if (officeSecurityProperties.isEnable()) {
            http.authorizeHttpRequests(
                            authorize -> authorize
                                    .requestMatchers("/doc.html", "/webjars/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                    .oauth2ResourceServer(
                            oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(
                                    jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(converter)
                            )
                    );
        } else {
            http.securityContext(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        }
        return http.build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you could consider.

#### Don't Enable

The easiest way is to not enable things from the beginning. You can disable the Spring Boot configuration and then publish your own configuration class with a `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation like so:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
// ... main class
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@ConditionalOnProperty("office.security.property")
public SecurityConfiguration {
    // ...
}
```

#### Programmatically Enable

It's trickier to turn something off that you've already turned on. You appear to already have something working for web security. For method security, change your annotation to:

```java
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = false)
public SecurityConfig {
}
```

And then publish the method interceptors on your own like so:

```java
@Bean
@Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
@ConditionalOnProperty("office.security.property")
static MethodInterceptor preAuthorizeAuthorizationMethodInterceptor() {
    return AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.preAuthorize();
}
```

This will publish `@PreAuthorize` support. You would [publish a method interceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html#enable-annotation) for each annotation that you want to enable the behavior for.